# How to create index for dynamic search strings

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, indexing

I have a little DB, for academic purpose only, and I have object tables at most.
I've created a entity-relationship model (ERM) in Power Designer and the program, by default, creates index for the serial id's for each table.

1. I want to know how do I use a index
   like that on a query.Say I would
   want to find a product by its id,
   but using its index.
2. Is it possible to do `select
   value(s) from supplierf where s.name
   LIKE '%search%' order by s.name`
   using a index to do a search like
   that? I know it's possible to create
   index for the name, but for a search
   like that I don't know how things
   work.

Let me say, that I do know that Oracle decides when or if it's worth using index in a query, but I may have to give, at least, a try on using indexs in my BD project

Answer (score 6):

1.
By defining a column as `PRIMARY KEY` (that's what your id column most likely is), Oracle implicitely creates an index for this column. It will most likely decide to use that index when you have a select with `WHERE id=123`). You can provide a [hint](http://www.psoug.org/reference/hints.html) in your query to make Oracle use the index (in most cases), but that should not be necessary for you.

2.
It is unlikely for Oracle to use an index for `LIKE` (unless you know that your text starts with the searched string and you can use 'xyz%'). See [Tony Andrews' post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124400/how-to-create-index-for-dynamic-search-strings/2126860#2126860) for more information about when and how to use an index for full table scans.

The article about [Oracle LIKE clause searches with text indexes](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_like_sql_index.htm) should provide information about a way to handle full text searches.

Comment: +1: Oracle automatically creates an index for a primary key if an index for the column(s) doesn't already exist.

Comment: Re (2), it **is** possible to create an index for searching with LIKE '%text%', though the likelihood of Oracle choosing to use the index is small.  You could use a hint to make Oracle use the index if you were sure it would perform better.

Comment: @Tony Andrews: Thanks for the additional info about indexes - adjusted my post and added link to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your point 1.): I'm not clear what you mean: if you assign indexes sensibly, you **can** use index hints to force index usage, but it's a far better idea to let the optimzer do it's work first and then, if your index is not being used, analyse ***why*** (it could be that index usage under specific circumstances is not the quickest way). For example, if you are combining a search by id with a search using the wildcard match,the optimizer may decide that, if it has to be a complete table scan anyway (because of your `'%search%'` term) that there is no added benefit using the index on your id column.

Regarding your point 2.): it is (very) unlikely that an index can be used if you are using a wildcard match at the beginning of your search term. For searches like that, take a look at the Oracle fulltext syntax here:

http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/text/index.html

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to do select value(s) from supplierf where s.name LIKE '%search%' order by s.name using a index to do a search like that? I know it's possible to create index for the name, but for a search like that I don't know how things work.

Yes, but Oracle may choose not to use the index based on statistics.  You can tell Oracle to use the index via a hint, but whether the index actually helps will depend on your data.  Suppose you have this table and index:

```
create table t (id integer primary key, text varchar2(50), other_cols...);
create index t_i on t (text);
```

You then do this select:

```
select * from t where text like '%something%';
```

There are two obvious ways this query can be answered:

1. Full table scan on T
2. Full index scan on T_I, then 1 ROWID lookup of T per result found in T_I.

Suppose T has 100,000 rows, and only 5 of them match your search criteria.  Suppose also that table T occupies 5000 blocks, and the index T_I occupies 1000 (i.e. only 20% of the size of T).

The actual cost of the queries in terms of reads is then:

1. 5000 reads (of T)
2. 1000 reads (of T_I) followed by 5 reads of T by ROWID = 1005 reads

Clearly in this case the index is better.  However, Oracle tends to assume that the LIKE query will return 5% of the rows (i.e. 5000 rows), so its estimated costs (in reads) will be:

1. 5000 reads (of T)
2. 1000 reads (of T_I) followed by 5000 reads of T by ROWID = 6000 reads

Hence in this example, Oracle will go for the full table scan although the index search would be quicker.  You could hint the query to use the index:

```
select /*+ index(t t_i) */ from t where text like '%something%';
```

However, note that this is only better if you are sure the query will return less than 5% of the rows most of the time.